# How can I deactivate notices in Apache?

Tags: php, performance, apache, error-handling, error-reporting

I'm new on a project and after cloning the code, I can see several notices on every http request.
I always enable notices on my apache's development environment and of course they are disabled on the production server, and not logged to apache's error log

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)`, apparently like default php configuration.

So I how to achieve the following in Apache:

- ignore at 100% those notices and performances isn't impacted
- handle every notices like a developement environment without logging them..

I continue to search in the Apache documentation.

Comment: Why don't you just modify your code so it not to produce Notices?

Comment: it's a work that i 'll do for sure !

Like i said, i'm new on this project and looking for ideas to optimise the code to handle there very high traffic ...

Answer (score 1):

The error notices are internal to PHP - all that Apache sees is data coming and going.  The performance is only improved if you are sending less data.

You will be better off looking at what modules you load with apache and how apache is setup - prefork or worker and how you have these setup. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html

Comment: ok
thank you for your answer. 
I've seen on documentation that apache works better with a prefork compilation.


We have two apaches with varnish and memcache on production, and two master-master mysql, but i haven't that information yet.


thx you again, i ll populate this post with those new informations, and all positives optimisations.